# Run multiple lines in the command prompt vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shell, cmd

I know how to run cmd in vb.net, by using the `Shell "cmd.exe /k <command>`command, but how do you execute multiple lines using it, or do you use something else?

Comment: What do you mean with _multiple lines_? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD commands are separated by the ampersand. For instance:

```
cmd.exe /k <command 1> & <command 2> & <command 3>
```

An example .NET solution would be:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k <command 1> & <command 2> & <command 3>")
```

For more see [**Microsoft's Command Shell documentation**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).